# unlink image only if exists in laravel

Tags: laravel

While updating the user image unlink image from public folder if exists otherwise do update the user with image. Currently I have no image for user. And while updating user from profile section I am getting this error **unlink('images/users') is a directory**. I want if image exists for user then unlink the image and upload the new one otherwise just upload the new image.

My controller:

```html
public function changeUserImage(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:10000',
        ]);
        $image = $request->file('image');
        if (isset($image)) {
            $imageName = time() . '.' . $request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            if (!file_exists('images/users')) {
                mkdir('images/users', 0777, true);
            }
            if (file_exists('images/users')){
                unlink('images/users/' . \auth()->user()->image);
                $image->move('images/users', $imageName);
                User::find(\auth()->user()->id)->update(['image'=>$imageName]);
            }else if (!file_exists('images/users')){
                $image->move('images/users', $imageName);
                User::find(\auth()->user()->id)->update(['image'=>$imageName]);
            }
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I haven't test it yet. Let me know if you have any questions.

Make sure to Import File: `use File`;

**UPDATED**

```
public function changeUserImage(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png|max:10000',
    ]);
    // Let get the current image
    $user = Auth::user();
    $currentImage = $user->image;
    // Let compare the current Image with the new Image if are not the same
    $image = $request->file('image');
    // The Image is required which means it will be set, so we don't need to che isset($image)
    if ($image != $currentImage) {
      // To make our code cleaner let define a directory for DRY code
        $filePath = public_path('images/users/');
        $imageName = time() . '.' . $request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        if (!File::isDirectory($filePath)){
            File::makeDirectory($filePath, 0777, true, true);
        }
        $image->move($filePath, $imageName);
        // After the Image has been updated then we can delete the old Image if exists
        if (file_exists($filePath.$currentImage)){
            @unlink($filePath.$currentImage);
        }
    } else {
      $imageName = $currentImage;
    }
    //  SAVE CHANGES TO THE DATA BASE
    $user->image = $imageName;
    $user->save();
    
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: The image is stored in images/users foldes but not saving in database.

Comment: Try this `Auth::user()->update(['image'=>$imageName]);` Instead of  `User::find(\auth()->user()->id)->update(['image'=>$imageName]);`

Comment: still not saved into database

Comment: Thanks livreson it worked. But why didn't update method worked??

Comment: I'm not sure why but you can try `$user->update([ 'image' => $imageName']);`. I dont really use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

To store the image: `$request->image->storeAs('images/users/', $file_name);`

To delete an image: `Storage::delete('images/users/'. $file_name);`

Comment: I am getting this error unlink(images/users/): Is a directory. Where do I put this code?

Comment: Its true, you have to pass the file name.